# Merge Master Branch to My Branch Not Working

Tags: git

I have problem with merging master branch latest changes to my feature branch. I make branch from master branch and I make changes to my branch. But master branch has new changes and I wanting to put changes in my branch so I doing this:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git pull origin master
git checkout mybranch
git rebase origin/master
```

Now my changes in my branch have disappearing. It's like master branch changes have overwriting them. How am I doing rebase from master so master does not overwrite my changes in my branch? I want to take master branch new changes and where conflict with my branch I want to fix those. I do not want automatic overwrite my changes in my branch,

Comment: Did you add then commit your changes before pulling? I guess not.

Comment: In the last line, try `git rebase master`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you yo try this:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git pull origin master
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
# Fix any conflicts that should pop up
git add $ANY_CONFLICTS
git rebase --continue
git commit --amend
git push -f origin mybranch
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Referance: https://jjasghar.github.io/blog/2014/10/13/git-rebase-and-git-detached-head-cheat-sheet/